# IBM ICP Deployment error , ErrorImgPull, ImgErrorbackoff

Tags: ibm-cloud-private

we have 5 node ICP cluster in local env,,, and we are getting ImagepullError and ImagePullBackoff errors while deploying resources. we found Image-manager service is terminating frequently. what do to get of this prob.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can run kubectl command to get the logs for image-manager-0 pod, the command is:

## kubectl -s 127.0.0.1:8888 -n kube-system logs image-manager-0

In addition, from the screenshot, seems there are some other pods are not Running status. Please ensure your system match the ICP hardware requirement. The below link lists the requirements.
https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSBS6K_2.1.0/supported_system_config/hardware_reqs.html

Answer (score 0):

After **ICP 2.1**, I no longer had to specify `-s 127.0.0.1:8888`.
I would try:

```
kubectl describe pod image-manager-2 -n kube-system | more
```